# SpringBoot Undertow : how to dispatch to worker thread

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, worker, undertow

i'm currently have a look a springboot undertow and it's not really clear (for me) how to dispatch an incoming http request to a worker thread for blocking operation handling.

Looking at the class **UndertowEmbeddedServletContainer.class**, it look like there is no way to have this behaviour since the only HttpHandler is a ServletHandler, that allow @Controller configurations

```
private Undertow createUndertowServer() {
    try {
        HttpHandler servletHandler = this.manager.start();
        this.builder.setHandler(getContextHandler(servletHandler));
        return this.builder.build();
    }
    catch (ServletException ex) {
        throw new EmbeddedServletContainerException(
                "Unable to start embdedded Undertow", ex);
    }
}

private HttpHandler getContextHandler(HttpHandler servletHandler) {
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(this.contextPath)) {
        return servletHandler;
    }
    return Handlers.path().addPrefixPath(this.contextPath, servletHandler);

}
```

By default, in undertow all requests are handled by IO-Thread for non blocking operations.
Does this mean that every @Controller executions will be processed by a non blocking thread ? or is there a solution to chose from IO-THREAD or WORKER-THREAD ?

I try to write a workaround, but this code is pretty uggly, and maybe someone has a better solution:

**BlockingHandler.class**

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface BlockingHandler {

    String contextPath() default "/";

}
```

**UndertowInitializer.class**

```
public class UndertowInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext configurableApplicationContext) {
        configurableApplicationContext.addBeanFactoryPostProcessor(new UndertowHandlerPostProcessor());
    }

}
```

**UndertowHandlerPostProcessor.class**

```
public class UndertowHandlerPostProcessor implements BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor {


    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(BeanDefinitionRegistry beanDefinitionRegistry) throws BeansException {
        ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider scanner = new ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider(false);
        scanner.addIncludeFilter(new AnnotationTypeFilter(BlockingHandler.class));
        for (BeanDefinition beanDefinition : scanner.findCandidateComponents("org.me.lah")){

            try{
                Class clazz = Class.forName(beanDefinition.getBeanClassName());
                beanDefinitionRegistry.registerBeanDefinition(clazz.getSimpleName(), beanDefinition);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                throw new BeanCreationException(format("Unable to create bean %s", beanDefinition.getBeanClassName()), e);
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory configurableListableBeanFactory) throws BeansException {
        //no need to post process defined bean
    }
}
```

**override UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.class**

```
public class UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory extends  AbstractEmbeddedServletContainerFactory implements ResourceLoaderAware, ApplicationContextAware {

    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    public EmbeddedServletContainer getEmbeddedServletContainer(ServletContextInitializer... initializers) {
        DeploymentManager manager = createDeploymentManager(initializers);
        int port = getPort();
        if (port == 0) {
            port = SocketUtils.findAvailableTcpPort(40000);
        }
        Undertow.Builder builder = createBuilder(port);

        Map<String, Object> handlers = applicationContext.getBeansWithAnnotation(BlockingHandler.class);
        return new UndertowEmbeddedServletContainer(builder, manager, getContextPath(),
            port, port >= 0, handlers);
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }
}

...
```

**override UndertowEmbeddedServletContainer.class**

```
public UndertowEmbeddedServletContainer(Builder builder, DeploymentManager manager,
                                        String contextPath, int port, boolean autoStart, Map<String, Object> handlers) {
    this.builder = builder;
    this.manager = manager;
    this.contextPath = contextPath;
    this.port = port;
    this.autoStart = autoStart;
    this.handlers = handlers;
}

private Undertow createUndertowServer() {
    try {
        HttpHandler servletHandler = this.manager.start();
        String path = this.contextPath.isEmpty() ? "/" : this.contextPath;
        PathHandler pathHandler = Handlers.path().addPrefixPath(path, servletHandler);
        for(Entry<String, Object> entry : handlers.entrySet()){
            Annotation annotation = entry.getValue().getClass().getDeclaredAnnotation(BlockingHandler.class);
            System.out.println(((BlockingHandler) annotation).contextPath());
            pathHandler.addPrefixPath(((BlockingHandler) annotation).contextPath(), (HttpHandler) entry.getValue());
        }

        this.builder.setHandler(pathHandler);
        return this.builder.build();
    }
    catch (ServletException ex) {
        throw new EmbeddedServletContainerException(
                "Unable to start embdedded Undertow", ex);
    }
}
```

**set initializer to the application context**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class).initializers(new UndertowInitializer()).run(args);
}
```

**finaly create a HttpHandler that dispatch to worker thread**

```
@BlockingHandler(contextPath = "/blocking/test")
public class DatabaseHandler implements HttpHandler {

    @Autowired
    private EchoService echoService;

    @Override
    public void handleRequest(HttpServerExchange httpServerExchange) throws Exception {
        if(httpServerExchange.isInIoThread()){
            httpServerExchange.dispatch();
        }

        echoService.getMessage("my message");
    }
```

}

As you can see, my "solution" is really heavy, and i would really appreciate any help to simplify it a lot.

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to do anything.

Spring Boot's default Undertow configuration uses Undertow's [`ServletInitialHandler`](https://github.com/undertow-io/undertow/blob/1.1.1.Final/servlet/src/main/java/io/undertow/servlet/handlers/ServletInitialHandler.java) in front of Spring MVC's `DispatcherServlet`. This handler [performs the `exchange.isInIoThread()` check and calls `dispatch()` if necessary](https://github.com/undertow-io/undertow/blob/1.1.1.Final/servlet/src/main/java/io/undertow/servlet/handlers/ServletInitialHandler.java#L160-L162).

If you place a breakpoint in your `@Controller`, you'll see that it's called on a thread named `XNIO-1 task-n` which is a worker thread (the IO threads are named `XNIO-1 I/O-n`).