# Spring Boot Undertow add both blocking handler and NIO handler in the same application

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, undertow

In my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27536751/springboot-undertow-how-to-dispatch-to-worker-thread) (thank @Andy Wilkinson) I figured out that all incoming requests to an `undertowEmbeddedServletContainer` are handled by a worker thread (blocking operation).

According to Andy, I try to add a `UndertowBuilderCustomizer` in order to override the `ServletInitializerHandler` to handle incoming requests with a non-blocking handler.

```
@Bean
public UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory undertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory(){
    UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory undertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory = new UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
    undertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.addBuilderCustomizers(new UndertowBuilderCustomizer() {

        @Override
        public void customize(Undertow.Builder builder) {
            builder.setHandler(new HttpHandler() {
                @Override
                public void handleRequest(HttpServerExchange exchange) throws Exception {
                    exchange.getResponseSender().send("test");
                }
            });
        }
    });
    return undertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory;
}
```

In this customizer I set the builder `rootHandler` for a NIO handler. 
But it is overriden by `UndertowEmbeddedServletContainer` at startup phase with a `ServletInitializerHandler`:

```
private Undertow createUndertowServer() {
    try {
        HttpHandler servletHandler = this.manager.start();
        this.builder.setHandler(getContextHandler(servletHandler));
        return this.builder.build();
    }
    catch (ServletException ex) {
        throw new EmbeddedServletContainerException(
                "Unable to start embdedded Undertow", ex);
    }
}
```

As the title of this question says: I'm trying to have both blocking and non-blocking handlers, where blocking handlers are managed through `@Controller` annotation, and where NIO handlers are managed by Spring.

I found a solution, but as a beginner, I don't know if it's a good one.

**HandlerPath annotation**

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
public @interface HandlerPath {

    public String path() default "";

}
```

**create bean implementing HttpHandler**

```
@Component
@HandlerPath(path = "/hello-nio")
public class HelloHandler implements HttpHandler{

    @Autowired
   HelloService helloService;

    @Override
    public void handleRequest(HttpServerExchange exchange) throws Exception {
        exchange.getResponseSender().send(helloService.sayHello("Josselin"));
    }  
}
```

**Create a simple Controller**

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    @ResponseBody
    public String sayHello(){
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

**Create a class implementing ServletExtension**

```
public class NonBlockingHandlerExtension implements ServletExtension{

    @Override
    public void handleDeployment(DeploymentInfo deploymentInfo, final ServletContext servletContext) {
        deploymentInfo.addInitialHandlerChainWrapper(new HandlerWrapper() {
            @Override
            public HttpHandler wrap(final HttpHandler handler) {

                WebApplicationContext ctx = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(servletContext);
                Map<String, Object> handlers = ctx.getBeansWithAnnotation(HandlerPath.class);

                PathHandler rootHandler = new PathHandler();
                rootHandler.addPrefixPath("/", handler);
                for(Map.Entry<String, Object> handlerEntry : handlers.entrySet()){
                    if(handlerEntry.getValue() instanceof HttpHandler){
                        HttpHandler httpHandler = (HttpHandler) handlerEntry.getValue();
                        String path = httpHandler.getClass().getAnnotation(HandlerPath.class).path();
                        rootHandler.addPrefixPath(path, httpHandler);
                    }
                }
                return rootHandler;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

In this method, the default `ServletInitializer` handler is bound to "/" context, and managed by spring, so all blocking requests could be handled by `@Controller`(s).
Then I try to discover all beans that are annotated with `@HandlerPath`, then add a new `prefixPath` to the `rootHandler` based on `@HandlerPath.path` property.

**Finally**

Create a directory META-INF.services

Create a file io.undertow.servlet.ServletExtension and add line:

```
org.me.undertow.NonBlockingHandlerExtension
```

**Result**

All is working like a charm, NIO handlers are called when binding URL are hit, so do blocking handlers.

Could anyone please let me know if this solution could be improved in any way?
Moreover, as NIO handler URLs are not managed by Spring, I guess I have to use `globaleMethodSecurity` and set `@PreAuthorize` to secure the NIO handler?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem lately and I discovered that `UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory` provides `addDeploymentInfoCustomizers()` which can be used to put custom `HttpHandler` at the beginning of handlers chain.

## Example

```
@Bean
public UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory embeddedServletContainerFactory(RootHandler rootHandler) {
    UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory = new UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();

    factory.addDeploymentInfoCustomizers(deploymentInfo ->
            deploymentInfo.addInitialHandlerChainWrapper(rootHandler::setNext));

    return factory;
}
```

Sample `RootHandler`

```
@Component
public class RootHandler implements HttpHandler {

    private HttpHandler next;

    @Autowired
    public RootHandler(...) {
    }

    @Override
    public void handleRequest(HttpServerExchange exchange) throws Exception {
        if (exchange.getRelativePath().startsWith("/service")) {
            handleServiceRequest(exchange);
        } else {
            next.handleRequest(exchange);
        }
    }

    private void handleServiceRequest(HttpServerExchange exchange) {

        // ...

        exchange.getResponseSender().send("OK");
    }

    public HttpHandler setNext(HttpHandler next) {
        this.next = next;
        return this;
    }
}
```